# Textarea without input functionality

Tags: html, textarea, chat

I am making an application with text-chat. I want to display the text output, but don't want to custom code an entire div, with a scroll bar, etc.

`<textarea>` seems to behave really nice for accepting text input. How can I disable inputting new values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent input in a textarea add the readonly attribute to it

```
<textarea readonly></textarea>
```